# PostgreSql not starting on Ubuntu 14.04 - 9.3/main (port 5432): down

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-9.3

I start it and says it started but it's not running.

```
postgres@zararlinuxvm:/var/run$ /etc/init.d/postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                          [ OK ] 
postgres@zararlinuxvm:/var/run$ /etc/init.d/postgresql status
9.3/main (port 5432): down
postgres@zararlinuxvm:/var/run$
```

My postgres.config looks like:

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost'
port = 5432
max_connections = 100
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'
unix_socket_permissions = 0777
```

The permissions/ownership of /var/run/postgresql look like:

```
postgres@zararlinuxvm:/var/run$ pwd
/var/run
postgres@zararlinuxvm:/var/run$ ls -l | grep postgresql
drwxrwsr-x 2 postgres   postgres     40 Dec 28 14:16 postgresql
```

Other info:

```
postgres@zararlinuxvm:/var/run$ whereis postgresql
postgresql: /etc/postgresql /usr/lib/postgresql /usr/include/postgresql /usr/share/postgresql
postgres@zararlinuxvm:/var/run$ whoami
postgres
```

I'm not sure what could be the problem, because there isn't even a process running nor is a port or socket being used.

```
postgres@zararlinuxvm:~$ netstat -an | grep 5432
postgres@zararlinuxvm:~$
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Try starting postgresql manually instead of starting the daemon. Since the status says down after you start it, it is running into an error after startup. You can also take a look at the logs.

Comment: What does pg_log say?

Comment: It's empty. Not even being written to. It was created but nothing in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could never get this to work.  However, since 9.4 is out, I went with that.  I did not install using the package manager (`apt-get`) and instead compiled from source as instructed in the [official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/install-windows.html).  That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

i was also having the same issue 
i solve it by

```
service postgresql start
```

here is my terminal log:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-available# service postgresql status
9.3/main (port 5432): down
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-available# service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                                        [ OK ] 
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-available# service postgresql status
9.3/main (port 5432): online
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-available#
```

Comment: `sudo service postgresql start` for my environment